# JSF crud popup opens before value gets submitted

Tags: jsf, datatable, popup, richfaces, crud

In my crud application I want to select a row and then display that row data in a popup. navigating to another page works and it displays the data. when I try to display it in my popup no values are displayed. I could be wrong but I think the popup opens before the method prepareView is done.

code block:

```
<h:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="&nbsp;"/>
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:commandLink id="myLink" value="Action" action="#{timeLoggingDetailController.prepareView}" rendered="#{item.timeLoggingId eq AdminTimeLogging.filteredId}" styleClass="auto-style5">
                                <rich:componentControl target="popup" operation="show"/>
                            </h:commandLink>
                        </h:column>
                    </h:dataTable>
                </h:panelGroup>
            </h:form>
            <rich:popupPanel id="popup" modal="false" autosized="true" resizeable="false" domElementAttachment="form">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Approval level" />
                </f:facet>
                <f:facet name="controls">
                    <h:outputLink value="#" onclick="#{rich:component('popup')}.hide();
                            return false;">
                        Close
                    </h:outputLink>
                </f:facet>
                <h:form id="submitForm">
                    <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                        <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ViewTimeLoggingDetailLabel_date}"/>
                        <h:outputText value="#{timeLoggingDetailController.selected.date}" title="#{bundle.ViewTimeLoggingDetailTitle_date}">
                            <f:convertDateTime pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" />
                        </h:outputText>
                        <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ViewTimeLoggingDetailLabel_description}"/>
                        <h:outputText value="#{timeLoggingDetailController.selected.description}" title="#{bundle.ViewTimeLoggingDetailTitle_description}"/>
                        <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ViewTimeLoggingDetailLabel_normalHours}"/>
                        <h:outputText value="#{timeLoggingDetailController.selected.normalHours}" title="#{bundle.ViewTimeLoggingDetailTitle_normalHours}"/>
                        <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ViewTimeLoggingDetailLabel_overtimeHours}"/>
                        <h:outputText value="#{timeLoggingDetailController.selected.overtimeHours}" title="#{bundle.ViewTimeLoggingDetailTitle_overtimeHours}"/>
                        <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ViewTimeLoggingDetailLabel_doubleTimeHours}"/>
                        <h:outputText value="#{timeLoggingDetailController.selected.doubleTimeHours}" title="#{bundle.ViewTimeLoggingDetailTitle_doubleTimeHours}"/>
                        <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ViewTimeLoggingDetailLabel_approvalLevelsId}"/>
                        <h:outputText value="#{timeLoggingDetailController.selected.approvalLevelsId}" title="#{bundle.ViewTimeLoggingDetailTitle_approvalLevelsId}"/>
                    </h:panelGrid>
                    <br />
                    <h:panelGrid  class="auto-style4">
                        <h:commandLink   action="#{timeLoggingDetailController.update}" value="#{bundle.EditTimeLoggingDetailSaveLink}" onclick="#{rich:component('popup')}.hide();" styleClass="linkbutton"/>
                    </h:panelGrid>
                </h:form>
            </rich:popupPanel>
        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>

</html>
```

Comment: May be your popuppanel is not update

Comment: well how do i update it then?

Comment: In your managedbean which is calling the method put the following code FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getPartialViewContext().getRenderIds().add("menuForm:addLeaveDialog");

Comment: hi, which method? the prepareView? I tried adding and makes no difference. The prepareView selects the row data from the datatable then the popup must open to display that selected data. When I use prepareView with a navigation case to a another page and then display the data it works. but when I want to display it in the popup it does not work

Comment: The prepareView returns a string that is used for a navigation case, is there anyway to return a method that will open the popup? so that it can display the values I selected?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use `<a4j:commandLink>`, it provides `oncomplete` event which is fired when the action completes.

This should work for you:

```
<a4j:commandLink id="myLink" value="Action" actionListener="#{timeLoggingDetailController.prepareView}" rendered="#{item.timeLoggingId eq AdminTimeLogging.filteredId}" styleClass="auto-style5">
    <rich:componentControl event="complete" target="popup" operation="show"/>
</a4j:commandLink>
```

Comment: tested but not working, the popup does not show up? used exact code

Comment: the popup does not work, but when I remove the event="complete" it pops up and shows the last selected row's value, but not the new value I clicked on, so the popup is still executed before method is done, which tells me im almost there, there just that last small change and it will work